# Instancemethod or function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Today I defined a class just for testing what comes next:

```
class B(object):
    def p(self):
        print("p")
```

And later I did this:

```
>>> type(B.__dict__['p'])
<type 'function'>
>>> type(B.p)
<type 'instancemethod'>
```

So, why? Aren't `B.p` and `B.__dict__['p']` the same object?

My astonishment just increased when a I tried this:

```
>>> B.__dict__['p']
<function p at 0x3d2bc80>
>>> type(B.__dict__['p'])
<type 'function'>
```

Ok, so far so good, the type is in both results `function`, but when I tried:

```
>>> B.p
<unbound method B.p>
>>> type(B.p)
<type 'instancemethod'>
```

What?!, Why? `unbound method` and `instancemethod`? Are those the same? Why two different names?

Well, It seems python is full of surprises!

And this is the python I'm using:

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:26) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: I don't know why someone downvote this question.

Comment: @PauloBu Well, now we are two!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a very nice question.

To clear a few things:

1. When a method name is accessed through its class (e.g. `B.p`) it said to be *unbound*.
2. When otherwise the method is accessed through its class' instance (e.g. `B().p`) is said to be *bound*.

The main difference between *bound* and *unbound* is that if *bound*, the first argument will be implicitly the instance of the **calling** class. That's why we have to add `self` as first argument to every method when we define it. When *unbound*, you'll have to pass explicitly the instance of the class which you want to apply the logic of the method.

For example:

```
class B(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'ok'

>>>B().foo()
ok
>>>B.foo()
Exception, missing an argument.
>>>B.foo(B())
ok
```

This is a basic explanation of *bound* and *unbound*. Now regarding to the `__dict__` weirdness. Any object in Python can define a `__get__` and `__set__` method, which control the access to them when they're attributes in a class. These are called *descriptors*.

In simpler words, when you access an attribute (property) of a class by its instance or class, Python doesn't return the object directly, instead it calls a `__get__` or `__set__` method that in turn returns a convenient object to work with.

Functions in Python override this `__get__` method. So when you issue `B.foo` or `B().foo` it returns an `instancemethod` type, which is a wrapper to `function` type (a wrapper that pass `self` as first argument implicitly). When you access the function through the raw class' dictionary, there's no call to `__get__` because you're not accessing them as a property of a class, hence the return value to be a *raw* function.

There's a lot to say about this topic, I tried to give a very simple answer to such a *clever* topic. You can find **definitive** information on Guido's blog article [The Inside Story on New-Style Classes](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html), very recommended.

**UPDATE**: About your last example:

```
>>> B.p
<unbound method B.p>
>>> type(B.p)
<type 'instancemethod'>
```

Notice that in Python's interpreter `>>>B.p` doesn't actually print the type of the object, instead it prints the object's `__repr__` method. You can check that by doing `>>>print B.p.__repr__()` and seeing that its the same result :)

Python's is full of indirection and delegation, that's what makes it so flexible.

Hope this clarify things a bit.

Comment: Note that the word _(un)bound_ is already the past participle, so _(un)bounded_ is nonsense

Comment: @Eric thank you and sorry for that. English ain't my mother tongue :(

Comment: Just to add to the confusion, there actually is a word _unbounded_, which means "without bounds": something that has no boundaries or edges. Perhaps you were thinking of that.

Comment: @PeterWestlake LOL I don't think so. I was referring to the state of the function. Which I think _unbound_ is ok. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @xndrme: Added a final words about the output of the interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

> So, why? Aren't `B.p` and `B.__dict__['p']` the same object?

No. Attribute access is magic; when a user-defined method is accessed by attribute name, either a bound method or unbound method is returned (This changes in Python 3; there are no longer unbound methods at all; you get a regular function if you access an instance method through the class object); accessing directly through the dict bypasses this magic.

> What?!, Why? unbound method and instancemethod?, Are those the same? Why two different names?

A user-defined method is of type `instancemethod` unless it was defined with the `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` decorator. It can either be a bound instancemethod (when accessed as an attribute of an instance) or an unbound method (when accessed as an attribute of the class).

(See the "User-defined methods" section of http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html for an explanation.)

Comment: "Attribute access is magic" : well, like all "magic" it only seems to be magic until you learn the trick ;).

Answer (score 2):

> So, why? Aren't B.p and B.**dict**['p'] the same object?

They aren't, obviously. Read this : https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod for more in-depth explanations.